# Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image

Tags: apt, kubuntu

Cannot update my system:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-124-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-128-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic but it is not installed
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-124-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic (= 4.4.0-124.148) but it is not installed
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-128-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic (= 4.4.0-128.154) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

After that I ran the command recommended above:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  app-install-data-partner ca-certificates-java freespacenotifier g++-4.8 gcc-4.8-base:i386 gcc-4.9-base:i386 gcj-4.8-jre-lib gir1.2-soup-2.4 git-bzr git-remote-bzr gstreamer0.10-nice
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-base gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio gstreamer0.10-x gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 iproute kde-base-artwork kde-config-pimactivity kde-runtime-dbg kde-style-oxygen
  kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins kdelibs5-dbg kubuntu-debug-installer latex-beamer libaccounts-qt1 libakonadi-kabc4 libakonadi-kcal4 libakonadi-notes4 libakonadi-socialutils4 libass4 libatk-wrapper-java
  libatk-wrapper-java-jni libavcodec56 libavresample2 libavutil54 libbaloopim4 libbaloowidgets4 libbind9-90 libbluedevil1 libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common
  libboost-date-time1.54.0 libboost-program-options1.54.0 libboost-python1.54.0 libboost-system1.54.0 libboost-thread1.54.0 libbsd0:i386 libc6-dbg libcalendarsupport4 libcdparanoia0:i386 libcdr-0.0-0
  libcgmanager0:i386 libclass-load-perl libcmis-0.4-4 libcolord1 libcolorhug1 libcrypt-passwdmd5-perl libdata-optlist-perl libdns100 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386
  libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libechonest2.1 libedit2:i386 libegl1-mesa-lts-wily libelf1:i386 libelfg0 libestools2.1 libevent-2.0-5 libexiv2-12 libexporter-lite-perl libfarstream-0.1-0 libgail18
  libgbm1-lts-wily libgcj14 libgcrypt11:i386 libgif4 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-wily libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-wily:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily:i386
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-wily libglapi-mesa-lts-wily:i386 libgle3 libgles1-mesa-lts-wily libgles2-mesa libgles2-mesa-lts-wily libglew1.10 libglib2.0-bin libgnome-2-0 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin
  libgnome2-common libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgnustep-gui0.22 libgnutls26:i386 libgpgme++2v5 libgphoto2-port10
  libgrantlee-core0 libgrantlee-gui0 libgraphicsmagick++3 libgraphicsmagick3 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libgtk-vnc-1.0-0
  libgtksourceview2.0-0 libgtksourceview2.0-common libgtop2-7 libice-dev libicu52 libidl-2-0 libidl-common libimobiledevice4 libindicate-qt1 libindicate5 libio-stringy-perl libisc95 libisccc90 libisccfg90
  libisl10 libjasper1:i386 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjpeg-progs libjpeg9 libkactivities-models1 libkalarmcal2 libkateinterfaces4 libkblog4 libkcal4 libkdcraw-data libkdcraw23 libkdecorations4abi1
  libkdepimdbusinterfaces4 libkdgantt2-0 libkfbapi1 libkgapi2-2 libkimap4 libkimproxy4 libkmanagesieve4 libkmbox4 libkontactinterface4 libkpgp4 libkrossui4 libkscreen1 libkscreensaver5 libksieve4
  libksignalplotter4 libktnef4 libkutils4 libkwineffects1abi4 libkwinglesutils1 libkwinglutils1abi3 liblept4 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblightdm-qt-3-0 liblinear1 libllvm3.6 libllvm3.6:i386 libllvm5.0:i386
  liblwres90 libmagickcore5 libmagickcore5-extra libmagickwand5 libmbim-glib0 libmikmod2 libmodemmanagerqt1 libmspub-0.0-0 libmusicbrainz5-0 libmysqlclient18 libmysqlclient18:i386 libnepomukcleaner4
  libnetworkmanagerqt1 libnih-dbus1:i386 libnih1:i386 libnm-glib-vpn1 liboath0 libokularcore4 libopenobex2 libopus0:i386 liborbit-2-0 liborbit2 liborc-0.4-0:i386 liborcus-0.6-0 libparse-debcontrol-perl
  libparted0debian1 libpciaccess0:i386 libpimactivity4 libplist1 libpoppler44 libpostproc52 libprocessui4a libprotobuf8 libpth20 libpthread-stubs0-dev libqgpgme1 libqmi-glib0 libqoauth1 libqpdf13 libqpdf17
  libqt4-dbg libqt4-opengl:i386 libqtglib-2.0-0 libqtwebkit4:i386 libraw9 libsctp1 libsendlater4 libsensors4:i386 libservlet3.0-java libsignon-qt1 libsm-dev libsoundtouch0 libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386
  libstdc++-4.8-dev libsvga1 libswscale2 libswscale3 libsystemd-daemon0 libsystemd-login0 libtelepathy-logger-qt4-1 libtheora0:i386 libtorrent-rasterbar7 libts-0.0-0 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libupower-glib1
  libusbmuxd2 libva-glx1 libvisio-0.0-0 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvte-common libvte9 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libwpd-0.9-9 libwpg-0.2-2 libwps-0.2-2 libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0 libx11-dev
  libx11-doc libx11-xcb1:i386 libx264-142 libxatracker2-lts-wily libxau-dev libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-util0 libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev
  libxen-4.4 libxklavier16 libxml2:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxt-dev libxtables10 libxv1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libzip2 lightdm lightdm-kde-greeter linux-headers-4.2.0-42
  linux-headers-4.2.0-42-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-124 linux-headers-4.4.0-124-generic linux-headers-generic-lts-wily linux-image-4.2.0-42-generic linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-42-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-124-generic linux-image-generic-lts-wily linux-signed-image-4.2.0-42-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-124-generic lksctp-tools m17n-contrib mp3info
  obex-data-server oxygen-cursor-theme pgf phonon-backend-gstreamer1.0 polkit-kde-1 python-blinker python-cups python-dbus-dev python-debian python-dirspec python-gconf python-gnome2 python-gtk-vnc
  python-gtksourceview2 python-imaging python-jwt python-lzma python-oauthlib python-parsley python-pexpect python-pil python-psutil python-ptyprocess python-pyorbit python-renderpm python-reportlab
  python-reportlab-accel python-twisted python-txsocksx python-ubuntu-sso-client python-urlgrabber python-vte python-xapian rtmpdump scdaemon shared-desktop-ontologies syslinux-themes-debian
  syslinux-themes-debian-wheezy texlive-luatex torsocks tsconf ubuntu-sso-client wmctrl x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev xfonts-mathml xorg-sgml-doctools xscreensaver-data
  xscreensaver-data-extra xscreensaver-gl xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-screensaver-bsod xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-wily xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-wily xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-wily
  xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-wily xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-wily
  xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-wily
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-wily
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-wily xtrans-dev xul-ext-ubufox
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-4.4.0 | linux-source-4.4.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 42 not upgraded.
87 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/44,2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 136 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Д/н] y
(Reading database ... 441166 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic_4.4.0-128.154_amd64.deb ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic (4.4.0-128.154) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic_4.4.0-128.154_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-128-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-128-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-128-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-128-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-extlinux 4.4.0-128-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-128-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-128-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-128-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic_4.4.0-124.148_amd64.deb ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic (4.4.0-124.148) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic_4.4.0-124.148_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-124-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-124-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-124-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-124-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-extlinux 4.4.0-124-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-124-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-124-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-124-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic_4.4.0-128.154_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic_4.4.0-124.148_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I tried to run:

```
$ sudo apt-get clean
```

and then:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

but with no result

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  app-install-data-partner ca-certificates-java freespacenotifier g++-4.8 gcc-4.8-base:i386 gcc-4.9-base:i386 gcj-4.8-jre-lib gir1.2-soup-2.4 git-bzr git-remote-bzr gstreamer0.10-nice
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-base gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio gstreamer0.10-x gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 iproute kde-base-artwork kde-config-pimactivity kde-runtime-dbg kde-style-oxygen
  kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins kdelibs5-dbg kubuntu-debug-installer latex-beamer libaccounts-qt1 libakonadi-kabc4 libakonadi-kcal4 libakonadi-notes4 libakonadi-socialutils4 libass4 libatk-wrapper-java
  libatk-wrapper-java-jni libavcodec56 libavresample2 libavutil54 libbaloopim4 libbaloowidgets4 libbind9-90 libbluedevil1 libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common
  libboost-date-time1.54.0 libboost-program-options1.54.0 libboost-python1.54.0 libboost-system1.54.0 libboost-thread1.54.0 libbsd0:i386 libc6-dbg libcalendarsupport4 libcdparanoia0:i386 libcdr-0.0-0
  libcgmanager0:i386 libclass-load-perl libcmis-0.4-4 libcolord1 libcolorhug1 libcrypt-passwdmd5-perl libdata-optlist-perl libdns100 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386
  libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libechonest2.1 libedit2:i386 libegl1-mesa-lts-wily libelf1:i386 libelfg0 libestools2.1 libevent-2.0-5 libexiv2-12 libexporter-lite-perl libfarstream-0.1-0 libgail18
  libgbm1-lts-wily libgcj14 libgcrypt11:i386 libgif4 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-wily libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-wily:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily:i386
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-wily libglapi-mesa-lts-wily:i386 libgle3 libgles1-mesa-lts-wily libgles2-mesa libgles2-mesa-lts-wily libglew1.10 libglib2.0-bin libgnome-2-0 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin
  libgnome2-common libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgnustep-gui0.22 libgnutls26:i386 libgpgme++2v5 libgphoto2-port10
  libgrantlee-core0 libgrantlee-gui0 libgraphicsmagick++3 libgraphicsmagick3 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libgtk-vnc-1.0-0
  libgtksourceview2.0-0 libgtksourceview2.0-common libgtop2-7 libice-dev libicu52 libidl-2-0 libidl-common libimobiledevice4 libindicate-qt1 libindicate5 libio-stringy-perl libisc95 libisccc90 libisccfg90
  libisl10 libjasper1:i386 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjpeg-progs libjpeg9 libkactivities-models1 libkalarmcal2 libkateinterfaces4 libkblog4 libkcal4 libkdcraw-data libkdcraw23 libkdecorations4abi1
  libkdepimdbusinterfaces4 libkdgantt2-0 libkfbapi1 libkgapi2-2 libkimap4 libkimproxy4 libkmanagesieve4 libkmbox4 libkontactinterface4 libkpgp4 libkrossui4 libkscreen1 libkscreensaver5 libksieve4
  libksignalplotter4 libktnef4 libkutils4 libkwineffects1abi4 libkwinglesutils1 libkwinglutils1abi3 liblept4 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblightdm-qt-3-0 liblinear1 libllvm3.6 libllvm3.6:i386 libllvm5.0:i386
  liblwres90 libmagickcore5 libmagickcore5-extra libmagickwand5 libmbim-glib0 libmikmod2 libmodemmanagerqt1 libmspub-0.0-0 libmusicbrainz5-0 libmysqlclient18 libmysqlclient18:i386 libnepomukcleaner4
  libnetworkmanagerqt1 libnih-dbus1:i386 libnih1:i386 libnm-glib-vpn1 liboath0 libokularcore4 libopenobex2 libopus0:i386 liborbit-2-0 liborbit2 liborc-0.4-0:i386 liborcus-0.6-0 libparse-debcontrol-perl
  libparted0debian1 libpciaccess0:i386 libpimactivity4 libplist1 libpoppler44 libpostproc52 libprocessui4a libprotobuf8 libpth20 libpthread-stubs0-dev libqgpgme1 libqmi-glib0 libqoauth1 libqpdf13 libqpdf17
  libqt4-dbg libqt4-opengl:i386 libqtglib-2.0-0 libqtwebkit4:i386 libraw9 libsctp1 libsendlater4 libsensors4:i386 libservlet3.0-java libsignon-qt1 libsm-dev libsoundtouch0 libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386
  libstdc++-4.8-dev libsvga1 libswscale2 libswscale3 libsystemd-daemon0 libsystemd-login0 libtelepathy-logger-qt4-1 libtheora0:i386 libtorrent-rasterbar7 libts-0.0-0 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libupower-glib1
  libusbmuxd2 libva-glx1 libvisio-0.0-0 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvte-common libvte9 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libwpd-0.9-9 libwpg-0.2-2 libwps-0.2-2 libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0 libx11-dev
  libx11-doc libx11-xcb1:i386 libx264-142 libxatracker2-lts-wily libxau-dev libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-util0 libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev
  libxen-4.4 libxklavier16 libxml2:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxt-dev libxtables10 libxv1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libzip2 lightdm lightdm-kde-greeter linux-headers-4.2.0-42
  linux-headers-4.2.0-42-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-124 linux-headers-4.4.0-124-generic linux-headers-generic-lts-wily linux-image-4.2.0-42-generic linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-42-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-124-generic linux-image-generic-lts-wily linux-signed-image-4.2.0-42-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-124-generic lksctp-tools m17n-contrib mp3info
  obex-data-server oxygen-cursor-theme pgf phonon-backend-gstreamer1.0 polkit-kde-1 python-blinker python-cups python-dbus-dev python-debian python-dirspec python-gconf python-gnome2 python-gtk-vnc
  python-gtksourceview2 python-imaging python-jwt python-lzma python-oauthlib python-parsley python-pexpect python-pil python-psutil python-ptyprocess python-pyorbit python-renderpm python-reportlab
  python-reportlab-accel python-twisted python-txsocksx python-ubuntu-sso-client python-urlgrabber python-vte python-xapian rtmpdump scdaemon shared-desktop-ontologies syslinux-themes-debian
  syslinux-themes-debian-wheezy texlive-luatex torsocks tsconf ubuntu-sso-client wmctrl x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev xfonts-mathml xorg-sgml-doctools xscreensaver-data
  xscreensaver-data-extra xscreensaver-gl xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-screensaver-bsod xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-wily xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-wily xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-wily
  xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-wily xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-wily
  xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-wily
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-wily
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-wily xtrans-dev xul-ext-ubufox
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-4.4.0 | linux-source-4.4.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 42 not upgraded.
87 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 44,2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 136 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Д/н] y
Get:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic amd64 4.4.0-128.154 [22,1 MB]
Get:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic amd64 4.4.0-124.148 [22,1 MB]
Fetched 44,2 MB in 26s (1 641 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                              
(Reading database ... 441166 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic_4.4.0-128.154_amd64.deb ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic (4.4.0-128.154) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic_4.4.0-128.154_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-128-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-128-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-128-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-128-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-extlinux 4.4.0-128-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-128-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-128-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-128-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic_4.4.0-124.148_amd64.deb ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic (4.4.0-124.148) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic_4.4.0-124.148_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-124-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-124-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-124-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-124-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-extlinux 4.4.0-124-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-124-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-124-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-124-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic_4.4.0-128.154_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic_4.4.0-124.148_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

df output:

```
$ df -h /boot
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       237M  230M     0 100% /boot
```

ls -lt output:

```
$ ls -lt /boot
total 224352
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root     1024 май  1 17:20 grub
-rw------- 1 root root  7146392 май  1 17:20 vmlinuz-4.4.0-122-generic.efi.signed
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 39641846 май  1 17:20 initrd.img-4.4.0-122-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1251054 апр 23 20:41 abi-4.4.0-122-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   190654 апр 23 20:41 config-4.4.0-122-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      255 апр 23 20:41 retpoline-4.4.0-122-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3898132 апр 23 20:41 System.map-4.4.0-122-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7144464 апр 23 20:41 vmlinuz-4.4.0-122-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 39590685 апр 14 10:06 initrd.img-4.4.0-119-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7146744 апр 14 10:01 vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic.efi.signed
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 36135739 апр 14 10:00 initrd.img-4.2.0-41-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 36134198 апр 14 10:00 initrd.img-4.2.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1251075 апр  2 21:05 abi-4.4.0-119-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   190604 апр  2 21:05 config-4.4.0-119-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     2747 апр  2 21:05 retpoline-4.4.0-119-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3896447 апр  2 21:05 System.map-4.4.0-119-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7144816 апр  2 21:05 vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     1024 июн 23  2017 extlinux
-rw------- 1 root root  6738424 дек 12  2016 vmlinuz-4.2.0-42-generic.efi.signed
-rw------- 1 root root  6736696 июл  7  2016 vmlinuz-4.2.0-41-generic.efi.signed
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1313590 июн 30  2016 abi-4.2.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184934 июн 30  2016 config-4.2.0-42-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3760051 июн 30  2016 System.map-4.2.0-42-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  6736496 июн 30  2016 vmlinuz-4.2.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1313640 июн 24  2016 abi-4.2.0-41-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184897 июн 24  2016 config-4.2.0-41-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3759492 июн 24  2016 System.map-4.2.0-41-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  6734768 июн 24  2016 vmlinuz-4.2.0-41-generic
drwx------ 2 root root    12288 мар 16  2016 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   182704 янв 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184380 янв 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184840 янв 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 янв  1  1970 efi
```

Comment: `the error message indicates a disk full error` -- can you show `df -h` output?

Comment: likely `df -h /boot`

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, I see that available space is zero. But how did it come to it? Everything was fine in the past. All I did recently was upgrading from 14 to 16.

Comment: Likely you've upgraded the kernel a few times, and so have old ones around. What is `ls -lt /boot` output?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I've just appended the command output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to remove the old kernels. Thanks to @JeffSchaller for helping me to understand this. To accomplish this I used this link titled: [RemoveOldKernels - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels). This is from the official Ubuntu docs on managing old kernels.

Additionally I needed to remove all the kernel packages named `linux-signed-image-x.x.x-xx-generic`.